# Cast Object into Generic List to get List of Items

Tags: c#, casting, generic-list

Is there any way that I can cast unknown object into generic list to get list of items from object by given ProperyName. 
Object can be any generic list like `List<Country>`, `List<Area>` or `List<Region>` but I need to get data by given `displayMember`.

For Example:

```
List<City> listCities = new List<City>(); //Cities data with (CityID, CityName)
object dataSource = listCities;
string displayMember = "CityName";
string valueMember = "CityID";
```

How to get List of `CityName` from `dataSource` object of object type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd have to use reflection, basically. For example:

```
// This assumes it really is just a List<T>...
IEnumerable list = (IEnumerable) dataSource;
Type elementType = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
PropertyInfo property = elementType.GetProperty(displayMember);
List<object> displayValues = list.Cast<object>()
                                 .Select(v => property.GetValue(v, null))
                                 .ToList();
```

(You'd want to add a bunch of error checking - for example, that `property` isn't `null`...)

Comment: GetGenericArguments line giving error: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'"

Comment: @Zeeshanef: Typo - fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. May be I could not ask my question clear. But `dataSource` object is `object` type which I think does not contain 'Select' definition. In First two lines I got Property Info from `object` which is OK. but How to get List<propertyName> from 'object'. May be I need 'IEnumerable<T>' but no idea how to use.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! My boss and I were wracking our brains trying to figure out how to do this!